# Azure Digital Twins APIs is not working with DefaultAzureCredential authentication method as described in the tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-digital-twins

I was following the [Coding with the Azure Digital Twins APIs tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/tutorial-code). I have prepared an Azure Digital Twins instance as described by the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-set-up-instance-portal). This is my role -

[image: account_role]

This is my Azure Digital Twins instance -

[image: ADT_instance]

This is my access permissions -

[image: user_access]

### DefaultAzureCredential method

Then, I have set up local Azure credentials as described by the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/tutorial-code#set-up-local-azure-credentials). I have signed in to Azure by Azure CLI and also with VS Code [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.azure-account).

[image: az_login]

[image: vsc_extension]

But when I was uploading model as instructed by the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/tutorial-code#upload-a-model), I got an Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException error. Here is the code of my client app -

#### Code

```cs
using System;
using Azure.DigitalTwins.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Azure;

namespace ADT_demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string adtInstanceUrl = "https://digitaltwinsek3p.api.wcus.digitaltwins.azure.net";

            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            DigitalTwinsClient client = new DigitalTwinsClient(new Uri(adtInstanceUrl), credential);
            Console.WriteLine($"Service client created – ready to go");



            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Upload a model");
            var typeList = new List<string>();
            string dtdl = File.ReadAllText("SampleModel.json");
            typeList.Add(dtdl);
            // Upload the model to the service
            await client.CreateModelsAsync(typeList);

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Error

```
Unhandled exception. Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication failed: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details.You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS70002: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.
Trace ID: 9e17bbaa-e120-4d31-af90-121216db0c00
Correlation ID: c2cf4df0-5257-4de6-892c-66855072ad95
Timestamp: 2021-01-18 11:17:11Z
 ---> MSAL.NetCore.4.22.0.0.MsalServiceException:
        ErrorCode: invalid_client
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details.You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS70002: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.
Trace ID: 9e17bbaa-e120-4d31-af90-121216db0c00
Correlation ID: c2cf4df0-5257-4de6-892c-66855072ad95
Timestamp: 2021-01-18 11:17:11Z
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.ThrowServerException(HttpResponse response, RequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.CreateResponse[T](HttpResponse response, RequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.ExecuteRequestAsync[T](Uri endPoint, HttpMethod method, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean expectErrorsOn200OK, Boolean addCommonHeaders)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.OAuth2Client.GetTokenAsync(Uri endPoint, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean addCommonHeaders)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.TokenClient.SendHttpAndClearTelemetryAsync(String tokenEndpoint)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.TokenClient.SendHttpAndClearTelemetryAsync(String tokenEndpoint)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.TokenClient.SendTokenRequestAsync(IDictionary`2 additionalBodyParameters, String scopeOverride, String tokenEndpointOverride, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.SendTokenRequestAsync(String tokenEndpoint, IDictionary`2 additionalBodyParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.CacheSilentStrategy.RefreshAccessTokenAsync(MsalRefreshTokenCacheItem msalRefreshTokenItem, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.CacheSilentStrategy.TryGetTokenUsingFociAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.CacheSilentStrategy.RefreshRtOrFailAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.CacheSilentStrategy.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.CacheSilentStrategy.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ClientApplicationBaseExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenSilentParameters silentParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilderExtensions.ExecuteAsync[T](AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilder`1 builder, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.MsalPublicClient.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(String[] scopes, IAccount account, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.SharedTokenCacheCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        StatusCode: 401
        ResponseBody: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.\r\nTrace ID: 9e17bbaa-e120-4d31-af90-121216db0c00\r\nCorrelation ID: c2cf4df0-5257-4de6-892c-66855072ad95\r\nTimestamp: 2021-01-18 11:17:11Z","error_codes":[70002],"timestamp":"2021-01-18 11:17:11Z","trace_id":"9e17bbaa-e120-4d31-af90-121216db0c00","correlation_id":"c2cf4df0-5257-4de6-892c-66855072ad95","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=70002"}
        Headers: Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
client-request-id: c2cf4df0-5257-4de6-892c-66855072ad95
x-ms-request-id: 9e17bbaa-e120-4d31-af90-121216db0c00
x-ms-ests-server: 2.1.11397.13 - KRSLR2 ProdSlices
x-ms-clitelem: 1,70002,0,99387912.9884,
Set-Cookie: fpc=AgEOOZYkMXtLt3KqlIDdhsj8dx2YAQAAADdll9cOAAAA; expires=Wed, 17-Feb-2021 11:17:11 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None,x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly,stsservicecookie=estsfd; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
Date: Mon, 18 Jan 2021 11:17:11 GMT

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex)
   at Azure.Identity.SharedTokenCacheCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.SharedTokenCacheCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenFromSourcesAsync(TokenCredential[] sources, TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex)
   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AccessTokenCache.GetHeaderValueFromCredentialAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AccessTokenCache.GetHeaderValueAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.DigitalTwins.Core.DigitalTwinModelsRestClient.AddAsync(IEnumerable`1 models, CreateModelsOptions digitalTwinModelsAddOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.DigitalTwins.Core.DigitalTwinsClient.CreateModelsAsync(IEnumerable`1 dtdlModels, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ADT_demo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\<location>\Program.cs:line 29
   at ADT_demo.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

### InteractiveBrowserCredential method

But when I used [InteractiveBrowserCredential method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-authenticate-client#interactivebrowsercredential-method), with an **app registration**, that has permissions to the Azure Digital Twins APIs, it worked fine.

#### Code

```cs
using System;
using Azure.DigitalTwins.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Azure;

namespace ADT_demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string adtInstanceUrl = "https://digitaltwinsek3p.api.wcus.digitaltwins.azure.net";
            string clientId = "<your-client-ID>";
            string tenantId = "<your-tenant-ID>";

            var credential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(tenantId, clientId);
            DigitalTwinsClient client = new DigitalTwinsClient(new Uri(adtInstanceUrl), credential);
            Console.WriteLine($"Service client created – ready to go");


            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Upload a model");
            var typeList = new List<string>();
            string dtdl = File.ReadAllText("SampleModel.json");
            typeList.Add(dtdl);
            // Upload the model to the service
            await client.CreateModelsAsync(typeList);

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Why authentication is not working in DefaultAzureCredential method?**

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) states that `DefaultAzureCredential` is just a wrapper that will try in order:

```
EnvironmentCredential
ManagedIdentityCredential
SharedTokenCacheCredential
VisualStudioCredential
VisualStudioCodeCredential
AzureCliCredential
InteractiveBrowserCredential
```

and as you can see, shared token credentials - the one producing your exception - will be used when found before trying visual studio code credentials or azure CLI credentials.

So the easy fix would be to replace `DefaultAzureCredential` with e.g. `AzureCliCredential`. The long term fix would be to wait for someone else to explain where the shared token credential entries are stored and get rid of them or update them.

Comment: I believe the issue the OP is running into is a known issue with the `SharedTokenCacheCredential`. They can exclude this credential from the `DefaultAzureCredential` using it's options `var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true });`